# Need help on a specific situation (beginner friendly)

Tags: analysis, strategy

I am a beginner and got myself into this situation. (I'm white) Is there any way to get out of it or some tips somebody can give me or is this situation hopeless? I would appreciate it if you took a tiny bit of your time to help me! (by the way, the pawn on Black rank is an accident it's supposed to be a bishop)
[image: ok]

Comment: How is there a pawn on Black's back rank?

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing  that out i made an accident on the board

Answer (score 2):

First off, if this is a game in progress against a person, it's generally considered cheating to be asking other people for advice. I'll assume you're against a computer or it's a friendly game and you have permission from your opponent to ask.

So... you're down a rook, a bishop, a knight, and a pawn. I'd call that hopeless if your opponent is any good. The main thing you have going for you is that Black hasn't yet developed their extra pieces, but they can do so very quickly.

1.Qxh5 wins a pawn and threatens 2.Qf7+ forking the king and rook. But if Black plays 1...Nd7 then 2.Qf7 isn't a check. And trying to get fancy with something like 1.Qxh5 Nd7 2.Qd5 doesn't really work because then Black plays 2...Bc5+. This breaks the pin and you'd lose have to give up your rook for the bishop, and Black's rooks are guarding each other. Even if Black doesn't see Qf7 and you win the rook for free, you're *still* down a bishop and knight, which is more than enough for Black to win if they're any good.